# How to remove errors warnings from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

Can we remove or hide errors and warnings from the console? Is there a way in Javascript or jQuery to prevent errors and warnings from being written to the console?

Comment: You can setup your browser for display only what you want

Answer (score 8):

You can redefine `window.console` to remove the logging features:

```js
var noOp = function() {}

window.console = {
  log: noOp,
  dir: noOp
  // all other methods...
};

console.log('foo'); // nothing happens
```

Alternatively you can call `console.clear()` to remove all existing items within the console.

*However* I wouldn't advise doing either of these. A much better approach would be to fix your codebase so that you avoid errors and implement graceful error handling where unexpected errors may occur. You can achieve the latter through `try`/`catch` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way you can manage it,

```
console.clear()
```

Or a `try/catch` block

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your console log function like below

```
console.log = function() {}
```

Comment: What about `console.dir()`, `console.debug()`... etc?

Comment: I just write another way of doing it for console logs only. hmm i saw your answer and i agree with you. @RoryMcCrossan